# How can i check which all users are logged into my application

Tags: java, session, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a web based application that uses userName and password for login.

now how can i check on certain time which all users are logged in at that very time.
i am using session management and no DB is used in application everything is on filesystem

Edit: 1 more silly doubt.. how to define a variable with application scope.. is this something of this sort?

```
<env-entry>
<env-entry-name>test/MyEnv2</env-entry-name>
<env-entry-type>java.lang.Boolean</env-entry-type>
<env-entry-value>true</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just collect all logged in users in a `Set` in the application scope. If your application is well designed, you should have a javabean `User` which represents the logged-in user. Let it implement [`HttpSessionBindingListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html) and add/remove the user from the `Set` when it's about to be bound/unbound in the session.

Kickoff example:

```
public class User implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

    @Override
    public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        Set<User> logins = (Set<User>) event.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("logins");
        logins.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        Set<User> logins = (Set<User>) event.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("logins");
        logins.remove(this);
    }

    // @Override equals() and hashCode() as well!

}
```

Note that you need to prepare the `Set` in the application scope so that it doesn't return `null` in above methods. You could do that in the same methods by a nullcheck, or with help of [`ServletContextListener#contextInitialized()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29).

Then, anywhere in your application where you've access to the `ServletContext`, like in a servlet, you can just access the logged-in users as follows:

```
Set<User> logins = (Set<User>) getServletContext().getAttribute("logins");
```

Comment: do we need to notify somewhere that the user class will be acting as session listner class?

Comment: No. You just have to put/remove it in session. The servletcontainer will automatically act whenever you put/remove something which implements `HttpSessionBindingListener`.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

[BalusC's approch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592961/how-can-i-check-which-all-users-are-logged-into-my-application/4593718#4593718) is more suitable, here by this approach you will get no of session not logged in Users. to do that you need to track HttpSessionBindingListener .

You can implement [`HttpSessionListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) and can track the logged in users

```
 public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
  // adding logging in user to some application data map or inserting it to DB
 }

 public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
  // remove logged in user to some application data map or inserting it to DB
 }
```

Comment: a simple instance `java.util.Map` having application scope

Comment: This doesn't count the logged in users. This just counts the sessions.

Answer (score 1):

A more scaleable solution would be to add a column like "loggedIn" to your users table in the database and set it to true when you log a user in. This would take bloat off the application server and also support a distributed environment if your application needs to run more than one box in the future.